# Display date on the basis of culture

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to display the date time (which I've placed on master page); in different language on the basis of current culture.

My javascript code on master:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var t;
        $(document).ready(function pageLoad() {
            setTimeout('SetTime()', 1000);
        });

        function SetTime() {
            var date = new Date();
            date.format = 'MM.DD.YYYY';
            $get('<%=lbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString() + " : " + date.toLocaleTimeString();
            setTimeout("SetTime()", 1000);
        }  

    </script>
```

It always shows datetime string in English even if I set different culture say: french or any other.

I tried other way through code-behind file of master page:

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Timer1_Tick);
}

void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Here, I'm getting date string in different language on the basis of culture selected. But I don't want to use Timer. Is there any way, I could achieve this without using timer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this,

```
function SetTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    var dateFormat = '<%=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern%>';
    var timeFormat = '<%=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern%>';
     var datetimeFormat = dateFormat + " " + timeFormat;
     var cultureSpecificValue= date.toString(datetimeFormat);
    alert(cultureSpecificValue);

   //Your Code

}
```

I am using "toString" function of [Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) datetime library in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

`toLocaleDateString` uses the locale of the client (and typically needs a browser restart for changes to take effect), and is not necessarily related to the culture used in the .NET thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can define this in your web.config file, like so:

`<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto:en-GB" uiCulture="auto:en"/>`

this should enable client-based format, while chosing the default if not defined by the client

modify as nessecary for your derired result.

if you want to set this on the specific page only, put the `Date.format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';`
 outside of your javascript function.

//Regards

Answer (score 0):

As you have the ScriptManager control an a page, you may use Microsoft Ajax Date object extension. For this purpose set ScriptManager's `EnableScriptGlobalization` property to `true`. Then you may use this script:

```
var localDate = new Date().localeFormat("F");
```

More about Microsoft Ajax extension here: [Microsoft Ajax JavaScript Base Type Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310818.aspx)